# Notepad++ Insert Line Below with Sift + Enter like in Eclipse?

Tags: notepad++

This shortcut should be working even when your cursor is in the middle of the current line.
Just like in Eclipse with `SHIFT` + `ENTER`.

Comment: Just for your information, you can browse the currently defined shortcuts by clicking Settings --> Shortcut Mapper. That said, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a macro:

1. Go to Macro --> Start Recording
2. Press <kbd>End</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to Macro --> Stop Recording
4. Macro --> Save Current Recorded Macro
5. Choose your hotkey, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (just <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> was not possible for me)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a 6 year old post, but I just figured out how to do this, and it's the first Google hit for this question.

Notepad++ will not allow you to assign "shift + enter" to a shortcut, but you can force it to do so.  Assuming Windows >= 7, the shortcuts config file is located in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`.  Under the internal commands node, add the line (or replace the corresponding shortcut id) `<Shortcut id="42058" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="13" />`

Do make sure to change the Scintilla shortcut that has the same key combination, `<ScintKey ScintID="2329" ... />`

Comment: This is better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Lightfire228 I know this is an old question but I decided to provide an step by step way to do this:

1. Open Notepad++ and from Macro menu hit 'Start Recording'
2. Press `"End"` Key, then press `"Enter"`
3. From Macro menu hit `'Stop Recording'`
4. From Macro menu hit `'Save Current Recorded Macro..'`
5. In the opened Window choose a name for the shortcut `'NewLine With Shift+Enter'` would be excellent. and fill `Alt`, `Shift` boxes and choose `Enter` from drop down menu.
6. Open `"C:\\Users\Your-Username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml"`
7. You should find your shortcut under `'<Macros>'` tag. mine was at line 8. The line should be like "`<Macro name="NewLine With Shift+Enter" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="13">`"
8. Change the Alt value from '`yes`' to '`no`'
9. Save the file
10. Go to Macro menu and choose `'Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro'`
11. From the opened window go to `'Scintilla commands'` tab
12. Find `'SCI_NEWLINE'` row (mine was number 9)
13. Double click on it and remove the `Shift+Enter` row from opened window
14. Restart Notepad++ and your done.

Just worked for me :)

Comment: You don't need a macro if you're already going to edit the xml anyway.  N++ already has a shortcut that does exactly this: `<Shortcut id="42058"` (can't recall the in-menu name).


I have since switched to vscode, which has both an Eclipse keymap addon, and a really extensible keyboard shortcut system.  The option for vscode is called "insert line below"